# copy constructor not called

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

```
#include <iostream>


int main(void)
{

class date {
private:
  int day;
  int month;
  int year;
public:
  date( )  { std::cout << "default constructor called" << std::endl; }
  date& operator=(const date& a) { std::cout << "copy constructor called" << std::endl; day=a.day; month=a.month; year=a.year; }
  date(int d ,int m ,int y  ) : day(d),month(m),year(y){ std::cout << "constructor called" << std::endl; }
  void p_date(){ std::cout << "day=" << day << ",month=" << month  << ",year=" << year << std::endl; }
  date& add_day(int d) { day += d; return  *this;}
  date& add_month(int d) { month += d;return  *this; }
  date& add_year(int d) { year += d;return  *this; }

};

class cdate {
  date n;
public:
   cdate(date b) : n(b)  { std::cout << "cdate constructor called" << std::endl;}
   void p_cdate() { n.p_date(); }
};

  cdate ncdate(date(30,1,2012));
  ncdate.p_cdate();
}
```

When  we  instantiate `ncdate` in this code:

1. temporary date object created when we call `cdate ncdate(date(30,1,2012));`
2. then i expect the call `n = b` and expect `n`'s copy constructor to be called.

`n`'s copy constructor is not getting called and  i cant figure out why. I know there is something wrong in  the 2nd assumption.  **Note:** this is test code only so don't  go over its performance, usability etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not defined a copy constructor for `date`, so the implicitly-declared copy constructor is used.

A copy constructor would look like `date(date const& other) { }`.  You have provided a default constructor (`date()`) and a copy assignment operator (`date& operator=(const date& a)`).  Neither of these is the copy constructor.

Comment: 1. I  am definitely sleepy. I misunderstood `date& operator=(const date& a)` to copy constructor.
2. WOW! people are really live on  this  website. Like the prompt response. thanks

Answer (score 0):

actually, I do not found the copy constructor in your code. the copy constructor shall declare as date(date& d), you only declare a assignment operation.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a copy constructor, but operator=.

```
date& operator=(const date& a) { std::cout << "copy constructor called" << std::endl; day=a.day; month=a.month; year=a.year; }
```

A copy constructor would look like this:

```
date(const date& a) { /*... */ }
```